# Application cache Laravel 4

Tags: web-applications, laravel, laravel-4, browser-cache, offline

Is it possible to use the appcache file (cache manifest) to cache Laravel views ?

The idea is to cache views and use the web sql database to access the web application offline. Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Laravel views are server-side rendered templates. Cache Manifest is a client-side mechanism for caching assets such as images, JS and so on. There's no integration between the 2 necessarily. How exactly would you like this to behave? Are you trying to cache Ajax request results?

Comment: I want that my web app can be used in offline mode. So, I thought about a solution that could be to do some views in HTML with javascript to inject data from web sql database and store them (html+js) in the browser with the cache manifest. Is it a good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `App::before()` and `App::after()` events... you can do this:

```
App::before(function() {
  $path = Request::path();
  // find cached file, if available, and send that instead?
});

App::after(function($request, $response) {
  // $response is the rendered HTML output.. do storage here.
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand how to store the views in local (client-side) with this solution ?